# Duplicate lightbox on galleries from Simple Lightbox (SLB) and Divi (MFP)

Tags: lightbox

I installed Simple Lightbox (SLB), but now when I click an image, I get two lightboxes popping up with the same image.  Using "inspect element" I can see that the top one is something like:

```
<div class="mfp-figure" ...<img class="mfp-img" ...
```

and after closing it, the remaining one is something like:

```
<span class="slb_template_tag ...<img ...
```

I suppose the second one is from the Simple Lightbox plugin because its class name starts with SLB.  I want to keep it because it has options like starting a slideshow automatically from clicking any image.

What is the top one (class names starting with MFP?) and how can I stop it from popping up?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the lightbox with class names starting with MFP is the "Magnific Popup" which is loaded by Divi.  This is supposed to be able to be disabled by going to Divi, Theme Options, and disabling the "Divi Gallery".  Unfortunately, doing so didn't stop the duplicate lightbox in my case.

Sundari Webdesign has a [guide to disabling the Divi lightbox](https://sundari-webdesign.com/divi-disable-divi-lightbox/) using a hack, which they say is now obsolete due to the configuration option above.

In the end the Divi configuration option didn't work for me, and I wasn't ready to try the hack to disable the Divi lightbox, so I just disabled the SLB lightbox instead.  It's unfortunate because the SLB lightbox has more features that I wanted.  Hopefully someday the Divi lightbox will be more easily replaceable by alternative lightboxes...